# Customise counters, cross references to environments

Tags: cross-referencing, environments, counters

I would like to make cross references to own defined counter on environments. So far I have tried the following,

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{entryc}[subsection]
\newcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{entryc}}
\newenvironment{qd}[1]{\refstepcounter{entryc}\noindent\textbf{Quasi Definition \thetheorem.}\begin{itshape}}
{\end{itshape}}
%
\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
This is the first chapter.

\section{First section}
This is the first section.

\subsection{First subsection}
This is the first subsection.

\begin{qd}{}\label{qd:emp} This is my environment. \end{qd}

\noindent In quasi definition \ref{qd:emp} it \dots

\end{document}
```

What happens is that

[image: Screen shot]

But I would prefer "...In quasi definition 1.1.1.1". Do anyone have some suggestions of how solve this? and How to avoid the 
        \noindent 
thing before the continuation of the text?

Additional information: if possible I would try to not use ntheorem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a solution that doesn't require modifying `\@currentlabel`. Since you've defined the counter `entryc` via `\newcounter`, it suffices to add the following three lines of code to your preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@entryc}{\thesubsection.}
\makeatother
```

The macro `\p@entryc` is empty by default, but can be changed via a `\renewcommand` statement to (just about) anything else -- say, `\thesubsection.`. The value of `\p@entryc` is prefixed to the value of `\label` to create the string that will be produced when a cross-reference to an entity (such as your `qd` environment) occurs that increments the counter `entryc`.

The following modified form of your MWE implements this idea. It also applies a couple of minor changes to the definition of the `qd` environment (such as using explicit `\par` statements), and it uses @karlkoeller's idea to load the `noindentafter` package and to execute `\NoIndentAfterEnv{qd}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{entryc}[subsection]
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@entryc}{\thesubsection.} % "prefix" for cross-referencing
\makeatother
\newenvironment{qd}
   {\par\refstepcounter{entryc}
    \noindent\textbf{Quasi Definition \thesubsection.\arabic{entryc}.}
    \em}  % suggest you use \em instead of \begin/\end {itshape}
   {\par} % use explicit \par statements to play it safe 
\usepackage{noindentafter}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{qd}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter}
  This is the first chapter.
\section{First section}
  This is the first section.
\subsection{First subsection}
  This is the first subsection.
\begin{qd}\label{qd:emp} This is my environment. \end{qd}
In quasi definition \ref{qd:emp}, it is shown that \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I did not really get why not require `\protected@...` or more precisely why is this required in the first case?

Comment: @nunatak - For every counter defined via a `\newcounter` instruction, a macro named `\p@<countername>` is created automatically; its default value is just the empty string. LaTeX automatically "prefixes" the contents of `\p@<countername>` to the representation of the counter produced by `\ref{<countername>}`. Given that this mechanism is around anyway, why not just use it for your purpose? The alternative that redefines `\@currentlabel` is not *wrong* -- it's just more work than needs to be performed. :-) Note, BTW, that it's not necessary to define a separate macro called `\thetheorem`.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that you have to define `\@currentlabel` to give the right value to your `\label`.

So, after assigning the new value to the counter `entryc` through `\refstepcounter`, you need to add `\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\thetheorem}` (in this case probably `\def\@currentlabel{\thetheorem}` is enough).

In other words, change the definition of your environment to

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{qd}{%
  \refstepcounter{entryc}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\thetheorem}%
  \noindent\textbf{Quasi Definition \thetheorem.}\itshape}{}
\makeatother
```

Note that I've removed the argument since you are not using it.

MWE

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{entryc}[subsection]
\newcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{entryc}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{qd}{%
  \refstepcounter{entryc}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\thetheorem}%
  \noindent\textbf{Quasi Definition \thetheorem.}\itshape}{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
This is the first chapter.

\section{First section}
This is the first section.

\subsection{First subsection}
This is the first subsection.

\begin{qd}\label{qd:emp} This is my environment. \end{qd}

\noindent In quasi definition \ref{qd:emp} it \dots

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

---

### ADDENDUM

I've just realised that you asked for a way to avoid issuing `\noindent` after the closure of your environment...

To achieve that, you can load the package `noindentafter` and issue the command

```
\NoIndentAfterEnv{qd}
```

The following MWE gives the same result of the image above.

```
\documentclass{book}
\newcounter{entryc}[subsection]
\newcommand{\thetheorem}{\thesubsection.\arabic{entryc}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{qd}{%
  \par\refstepcounter{entryc}\protected@edef\@currentlabel{\thetheorem}%
  \noindent\textbf{Quasi Definition \thetheorem.}\itshape}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{noindentafter}
\NoIndentAfterEnv{qd}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First chapter}
This is the first chapter.

\section{First section}
This is the first section.

\subsection{First subsection}
This is the first subsection.

\begin{qd}\label{qd:emp} This is my environment. \end{qd}

In quasi definition \ref{qd:emp} it \dots

\end{document}
```

Note that now you can even remove blank lines before and after the environment...

Comment: great, it seems to work excellent, even with `hyperref` Thanks